# Why does this correlated subquery work? (SQLZOO Select within Select 7)

Tags: sql

So you don't have to go searching out for it, the data they're presenting for the question set looks like this and the table is called `world`

```
name        continent   area    population  gdp
Afghanistan Asia        652230  25500100    20343000000
Albania     Europe      28748   2831741     12960000000
Algeria     Africa      2381741 37100000    188681000000
Andorra     Europe      468     78115       3712000000
Angola      Africa      1246700 20609294    100990000000
```

They present an exercise where you use a query to select the largest country by area in each continent. They do most of it for you so getting to the answer isn't hard. This is the correct query:

```
SELECT continent, name, area FROM world x
  WHERE area >= ALL
   (SELECT area FROM world y
    WHERE y.continent=x.continent
      AND area>0)
```

I can understand what must be happening for it to work, but not why. y.continent = x.continent must by some sort of fancy GROUP BY, but... the lesson doesn't explain it and I'd really like to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: I don't know which DBMS that site uses, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a loop, or grouping. Lets picture the rowset represented as aliased as `x` in the query:

```
name        continent   area    population  gdp
Afghanistan Asia        652230  25500100    20343000000
Albania     Europe      28748   2831741     12960000000
Algeria     Africa      2381741 37100000    188681000000
Andorra     Europe      468     78115       3712000000
Angola      Africa      1246700 20609294    100990000000
```

Now lets add an extra column that "contains" the subquery<sup>1</sup>, with the outer `x` value substituted:

```
name        continent   area    population  gdp          subquery
Afghanistan Asia        652230  25500100    20343000000  (select area FROM world y WHERE y.continent='Asia' AND area>0)
Albania     Europe      28748   2831741     12960000000  (select area FROM world y WHERE y.continent='Europe' AND area>0)
Algeria     Africa      2381741 37100000    188681000000 (select area FROM world y WHERE y.continent='Africa' AND area>0)
Andorra     Europe      468     78115       3712000000   (select area FROM world y WHERE y.continent='Europe' AND area>0)
Angola      Africa      1246700 20609294    100990000000 (select area FROM world y WHERE y.continent='Africa' AND area>0)
```

Let's represent those results that are returned by the subquery:

```
name        continent   area    population  gdp          subquery
Afghanistan Asia        652230  25500100    20343000000  (652230)
Albania     Europe      28748   2831741     12960000000  (28748,468)
Algeria     Africa      2381741 37100000    188681000000 (2381741,1246700)
Andorra     Europe      468     78115       3712000000   (28748,468)
Angola      Africa      1246700 20609294    100990000000 (2381741,1246700)
```

Now, for each row, we compare our `area` column against *each* value returned by the subquery. That's what the `ALL` forces - the `WHERE` clause is only satisfied if all of those comparisons are true. And the nature of the comparison (`>=`) means that its only true across all comparisons for the country within each continent with the largest `area`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since it's a correlated subquery, it's effectively evaluated once per row, so I think it's reasonable to show what is evaluated on a per-row basis. Note that a naive implementation *may* in fact evaluate the subquery a row at a time and so it will e.g. gather all of the areas within Europe (and Africa) twice whilst processing the entire outer query.

Comment: Thank you, this makes complete sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want the subquery to return `area` values for a specific continent. In other words, you want to compare the `area` of a country with `area` of all countries **being on the same continent**.

For example, for the second row you compare `28748` with all values in sequence `(28748, 468)` when you evaluate the condition. That sequence is returned by the subquery, and it considers the fact that you want to compare only with countries in Europe.

EDIT: you ask how the nested query do the `group by`. The answer is: *it does not*. Due to the fact that the data have just one country per continent with largest area it may seems that we perform the group by. However if we have a different data:

```
name        continent   area    population  gdp
--------------------------------------------------------
Afghanistan Asia        652230  25500100    20343000000
Pakistan    Asia        652230  2500100     2034300000
```

then we return both rows for one `continent` value, since they both satisfy the condition that you want a country with largest `area` in `continent`.

Comment: I still don't understand how the inner `WHERE` clause forces the output to be grouped by continent such that the `>= ALL` operator compares the area to the areas of  one continent at a time. In my head, what's happening behind the scenes is some kind of for loop, but I don't understand exactly why that's happening.